# ELK Stack - Customize autogenerated field mappings

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, geoip

I've got a very basic ELK stack setup and passing logs to it via syslog. I have used inbuilt grok patterns to split the logs in to fields. But the field mappings are auto-generated by logstash elasticsearch plugin and I am unable to customize them.

For instance, I create a new field by name "dst-geoip" using logstash config file (see below):

```
geoip {
  database => "/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat" ### Change me to location of GeoLiteCity.dat file
    source => "dst_ip"
    target => "dst_geoip"
    fields => [ "ip", "country_code2", "country_name", "latitude", "longitude","location" ]
    add_field => [ "coordinates", "%{[dst_geoip][latitude]},%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
    add_field => [ "dst_country", "%{[dst_geoip][country_code2]}"]
    add_field => [ "flow_dir", "outbound" ]
}
```

I want to assign it the type "geo_point" which I cannot edit from Kibana. Online documents mentions manually updating the mapping on respective index using ElasticSearch APIs. But Logstash generates many indices (one per day). If I update one index, will the mapping stay the same in future indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a "[template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/indices-templates.html)".

Comment: That is it! Your answer took me down a rabbit hole exploring ES templates. Finally I found this [article](https://michael.lustfield.net/misc/geo-point-with-elasticsearch-2x) which matches what I want to do. But there seems to be no simple way to test a template json file unlike logstash conf file. I was able to coerce mapping for one field type, but when I added another it didn't work as expected. Any suggestions or best practices how to develop the pattern file?

Comment: For testing, apply the template to a non-production index.  Remember that field mappings can't be changed after the index is created, so keep deleting the test index until you get everything working the way you want.